# PublicSuffix.org -- там прямо все TLD есть?

Tags: dns

В publicsuffix.org/ вот прямо все возможные на сегодняшний день и доступные в интернете tld есть? Он сразу же обновляется, когда что-то новое? Можно использовать для валидации tld в продакшене?

Comment: Вам лучше спросить на самом сайте, но я вижу там "The Public Suffix List is an initiative of Mozilla, but is maintained as a community resource." С другой стороны, сообщество, скорее всего, добавит новый домен быстрее, чем его успеет кто-то зарегистрировать. А вообще - оффтопик.

Answer (score 0):

актуальную информацию о tld лучше черпать из первоисточника — с сайта [организации iana, которая и занимется их регистрацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA).

например, список доменов верхнего уровня: [root zone db](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db).

Comment: в public suffix есть также домены и 3ьего уровня, а https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db нет.

Comment: по ссылке — список tld, зарегистрированных этой организацией. а домены более высоких уровней регистрируются другими организациями/людьми.